# Android Firebase getChildrenCount() not counting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to count the amount of data that has been entered into a specific child into a firebase database.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

if (!registerVote) {
        String user = dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();
        myFB.child(uniquePostID).child(dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);


        final Animation likeRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotatelike);
        final Animation likeZoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.zoomlike);
        AnimationSet multiLike = new AnimationSet(false);
        multiLike.addAnimation(likeRotate);
        multiLike.addAnimation(likeZoom);
        viewHolder.postVoteBtn.startAnimation(multiLike);

        long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.child(uniquePostID).child(dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).getChildrenCount();
        viewHolder.display.setText(Long.toString(numOfLikes));
        Log.d("LONG", Long.toString(numOfLikes));

        registerVote = false;
    }
```

I use the data snapshot to add to the database at child

```
myFB.child(uniquePostID).child(dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
```

but then when I use

```
long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot.child(uniquePostID).child(dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).getChildrenCount();
viewHolder.display.setText(Long.toString(numOfLikes));
```

It always shows as 0 and does not register anything. Each time a different account likes a post, a name is added to the child that matches the post ID. I want to use the getChildrenCount() to count every name that has like a certain post. I have also noticed that getChildrenCount() will perform the count on preloaded data only, my need is to have the data be retrieved in real time.

```
    {
  "Blog" : {
    "-KgM1HzLwU1RMx13Z41J" : {
      "desc" : "Feeling good",
      "title" : "Smashed the gym"
    },
    "-KgM1NlrcBTYUhUYWYBR" : {
      "desc" : "Really didn't feel like leaving the house today, so I played call of duty all day.",
      "title" : "Stayed inside"
    },
    "-KgM1PfgkzSeBxUWi_3t" : {
      "desc" : "Nothing helps clear your mind like time with friends",
      "title" : "Spending time with friends"
    },
    "-KgM1Wg54bERKNUyKnE2" : {
      "desc" : "But don't be afraid to dream big",
      "title" : "Everyone starts small"
    },
    "-KgM1Zojv7q5FhRi_a3u" : {
      "desc" : "Finally managed to break my personal best I'd had for months!",
      "title" : "New gym PB"
    },
    "-KgOmll6K6o_sv1JEUcn" : {
      "desc" : "A years worth of work comes to an end today, pretty nervous!",
      "title" : "Big presentation today"
    },
    "-KgP1bC4BlAe88XyN_VV" : {
      "desc" : "time to present",
      "title" : "let's go"
    },
    "-KgPE7DI2j7R1QLiL3Bb" : {
      "Likers" : {
        "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : "Joe Bloggs"
      },
      "desc" : "You've got this",
      "title" : "Stay positive"
    },
    "-KgPG7siKLWKzij1Lu3d" : {
      "desc" : "John is looking at this right now",
      "title" : "Honours presentation"
    },
    "-Kne46iBe6ooNFKTv_8w" : {
      "desc" : "bugs?",
      "email" : "Joe Bloggs",
      "title" : "new"
    }
  },
  "Engagement" : {
    "-KgP1bC4BlAe88XyN_VV" : {
      "Likers" : {
        "JXxWjn9nvQcNsvaf3CO7HqUNKKi2" : "Bob Smith",
        "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : "Joe Bloggs"
      },
      "stg15QKZFhNmTCYrgL5PtQ4wxJf2" : "Bob Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo the editor won't let me include a picture of it but the hierarchy of the child I wish to query is uniquePostID > Likers > names that I wish to count

Comment: We don't need a picture of the JSON tree. Please add the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console.

Comment: Done. @AlexMamo

Comment: What would you like `numOfLikes` to count? I see `Likers` in both nodes, `Engagement` and `Blog`.

Comment: I would like `numOfLikes` to count `Likers` from `Engagement`. `Blog` has since been updated not to take in any values of that kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot
  .child("Engagement")
  .child(uniquePostID)
  .child("Likers")          
  .getChildrenCount();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to have this refresh the data in the database after processing this? It will not process the like in the application with new data, only the preloaded data.

Comment: Once you get it, you can do what you want with that value.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're missing the `Likers` level from your JSON in your code:

```
long numOfLikes = dataSnapshot
  .child(uniquePostID)
  .child("Likers")          
  .child(dbAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
  .getChildrenCount();
```